# Homebrew formula how and where to place media files needed by executables in /bin

Tags: homebrew

First homebrew formula, trying to migrate a primarily Python project from disutils to homebrew as it now requires quite a lot more than just python modules.

I've written a cli, in python, that needs access to template files, a some media files like fonts and images.

My directory structure (in the repository) looks like this:

```
/klibs
    /bin
        klibs  # the cli
    /lib
        /font
        /img
        /template
    /klibs
        __init__.py # and the rest of the custom module
```

If I understand things right, to install the CLI I simply need:

```
bin.install("bin/klibs")
```

But that program needs access to everything in lib. I broadly understand that I just need to install that lib folder somewhere (...though specifically, I don't fully understand where...) inside Cellar and then symlink it. But I don't understand how this is achieved, or perhaps how it's *best* achieved as per homebrew cannon.

Lil help?